# email is not registered. email checking, email validation kotlin

Tags: android, regex, kotlin, email-validation

I need to register this email `apptest@i.ua`. However, it doesn't register. Other emails I've tried worked fine, but emails with this domain (`i.ua`) doesn't. Is there something I need to add for it to work?

```
val emailValid: Boolean = Pattern.matches("^((?!.*?\\.\\.)[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\!\\#\\\$\\%\\&\\'*\\+\\-\\/\\=\\?\\^_`\\{\\|\\}\\~]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)\$", email)
    if (!emailValid){
        signup_username.error = getString(R.string.email_error_not_valid)
        username.requestFocus()
        return
    }
```

Comment: This might be a formatting issue, but I'll still ask. Did you try registering `@i.ua`, and it didn't get registered? Isn't that your goal?

Comment: @Zoe All emails register except where there is this "@i.ua"

Comment: @Zoe This is the existing email. But in my application does not register

Comment: Ok, so all  other (of those you've tried) emails with a different domain register?

Comment: @Zoe Yes, But I need to have this one registered too

Comment: I've edited your question to try to make it clearer. If I misunderstood something, feel free to roll back.

Comment: @Zoe Thank you)